# Visual Basic XNA Gaussian Blur Function

Tags: c#, vb.net, xna, blur, gaussian

I've spent hours looking for a Gaussian blur function in VB that blurs texture2Ds. I didn't find one, so I made one myself, with the help of a blog post and a friend. Here it is, for any of you searching for it (I know this isnt a question, but it should hopefully help some of you out)

```
Public Shared Function blurImage(p As player, img As Texture2D, sb As SpriteBatch, Optional radius As Integer = 2, Optional amount As Single = 1.0F) As Texture2D
    Dim sigma As Single = radius / amount : Dim kernel As Single() = New Single(radius * 2) {} : Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim twoSigmaSquare As Single = 2.0F * sigma * sigma : Dim sigmaRoot As Single = CSng(Math.Sqrt(twoSigmaSquare * Math.PI))
    Dim offsetsHoriz As Vector2() = New Vector2(radius * 2) {} : Dim offsetsVert As Vector2() = New Vector2(radius * 2) {}
    Dim effect As Effect = content.Load(Of Effect)("Effects\GaussianBlur")

    For i As Integer = -radius To radius
        index = i + radius
        offsetsHoriz(index) = New Vector2(i * 1.0F / img.Width, 0F)
        offsetsVert(index) = New Vector2(0F, i * 1.0F / img.Height)
    Next

    Dim total As Single = 0F : Dim distance As Single = 0F : index = 0
    For i As Integer = -radius To radius
        distance = i * i : index = i + radius
        kernel(index) = CSng(Math.Exp(-distance / twoSigmaSquare)) / sigmaRoot
        total += kernel(index)
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To kernel.Length - 1 : kernel(i) /= total : Next

    Dim renderTarget1 As Texture2D = New RenderTarget2D(Game.graphics.GraphicsDevice, img.Width, img.Height, False, Game.graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat, DepthFormat.None)
    Dim renderTarget2 As Texture2D = New RenderTarget2D(Game.graphics.GraphicsDevice, img.Width, img.Height, False, Game.graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat, DepthFormat.None)

    If effect Is Nothing Then Throw New InvalidOperationException("GaussianBlur.fx effect not loaded.")

    Dim outputTexture As Texture2D = Nothing
    Dim srcRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height)
    Dim destRect1 As New Rectangle(0, 0, renderTarget1.Width, renderTarget1.Height)
    Dim destRect2 As New Rectangle(0, 0, renderTarget2.Width, renderTarget2.Height)

    Game.graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget1)

    effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques("GaussianBlur")
    effect.Parameters("weights").SetValue(kernel)
    effect.Parameters("colorMapTexture").SetValue(img)
    effect.Parameters("offsets").SetValue(offsetsHoriz)

    sb.Begin(0, BlendState.Opaque, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, effect)
    sb.Draw(img, destRect1, Color.White)
    sb.[End]()

    Game.graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget2)
    outputTexture = DirectCast(renderTarget1, Texture2D)

    effect.Parameters("colorMapTexture").SetValue(outputTexture)
    effect.Parameters("offsets").SetValue(offsetsVert)

    sb.Begin(0, BlendState.Opaque, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, effect)
    sb.Draw(outputTexture, destRect2, Color.White)
    sb.End()

    Game.graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(Nothing)
    outputTexture = DirectCast(renderTarget2, Texture2D)

    Return outputTexture
End Function
```

Comment: There is also a file you need to download for this to work (called GaussianBlur.fx), here is a link to the blog post that supplies it: (just place it into a folder named 'Effects' in your project content) http://www.dhpoware.com/demos/xnaGaussianBlur.html

Comment: Reformulate as a question and post your solution as an answer.

Comment: (nice to see power of VB)